# SQL Server FOR JSON Path Nested Array

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-json

We are trying to use FOR JSON Path in SQL Server 2016 for forming a Nested Array from a SQL Query.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT A, 
B.name as [child.name],
B.date as [child.date]
 from Table 1 join Table 2 on Table 1.ID=Table 2.ID FOR JSON PATH
```

Desired Output:

```
[{
A:"text",
   "child:"[
         {"name":"value", "date":"value"},
         {"name":"value", "date":"value"}

       ]
}]
```

However what we are getting is:

```
 [{
    A:"text",
    "child:" {"name":"value", "date":"value"}
  },
{
   A:"text",
  "child":{"name":"value", "date":"value"}
}]
```

How can we use FOR JSON PATH to form nested child array.

Comment: It would help to have sample input data (in the form of inserts) but basically nested JSON is generated based on the input tables. If you pre join your tables into a flat structure as a subtable or CTE and then generate JSON off that it should give a flat JSON structure.

Answer (score 5):

instead of join use nested query, e.g.:

```
SELECT A
     , child=(
           SELECT B.name as [child.name]
                , B.date as [child.date] 
           FROM Table 2
           WHERE Table 2.ID = Table 1.ID 
           FOR JSON PATH
       )
from Table 1 FOR JSON PATH
```

(the query in the question is broken af so this query is just as broken but should give you the idea)

Comment: thanks gordy for your reply..but I was looking for a way to do this using JOINS..as my query is much bigger and has left joins and inner joins as well.

Comment: Also I am not getting any values for "child" only A is present in the JSON.

Comment: the problem with the above is that the WHERE clause will generate the same exact output as OP got.

Comment: @adrien are you sure, just to confirm this query matches op's desired output exactly: `select x.a, child = (select y.name, y.date from (values ('value', 'value'), ('value', 'value')) y(name, date) for json path) from (values ('text')) x(a) for json path`

Answer (score 1):

This should produce the output you want. Subqueries are definitely the way to go. Trying to use joins just adds complexity that isn't needed.

```
DECLARE @parents TABLE (ParentID int, [Name] nvarchar(max))
DECLARE @children TABLE (ChildID int, ParentID int, [Name] nvarchar(max), BirthDate datetime)

INSERT @parents (ParentID, [Name]) VALUES (1, 'Bob')
INSERT @children (ChildID, ParentID, [Name], BirthDate) VALUES (1,1, 'Billy','4-JUL-2000')
INSERT @children (ChildID, ParentID, [Name], BirthDate) VALUES (2,1, 'Joan','19-SEP-2005')
INSERT @children (ChildID, ParentID, [Name], BirthDate) VALUES (3,1, 'Sam','20-JAN-2009')
INSERT @parents (ParentID, [Name]) VALUES (2, 'Joe')
INSERT @children (ChildID, ParentID, [Name], BirthDate) VALUES (1,2, 'Billy','4-JUL-2000')
INSERT @children (ChildID, ParentID, [Name], BirthDate) VALUES (2,2, 'Joan','19-SEP-2005')
INSERT @children (ChildID, ParentID, [Name], BirthDate) VALUES (3,2, 'Sam','20-JAN-2009')
INSERT @parents (ParentID, [Name]) VALUES (3, 'Sarah')
INSERT @children (ChildID, ParentID, [Name], BirthDate) VALUES (1,3, 'Billy','4-JUL-2000')
INSERT @children (ChildID, ParentID, [Name], BirthDate) VALUES (2,3, 'Joan','19-SEP-2005')
INSERT @children (ChildID, ParentID, [Name], BirthDate) VALUES (3,3, 'Sam','20-JAN-2009')

SELECT 
    A = [Name]
    ,child =JSON_QUERY((
           SELECT [name] = [Name],
                [date] = BirthDate
           FROM @children c
           WHERE c.ParentID = p.ParentID
           FOR JSON PATH
       ))
FROM 
    @parents p
FOR JSON PATH
```

I create scalar functions that generate the JSON for the subqueries.
For example (assume that the table variables are actually tables):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ChildrenJSON(@ParentID int)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
BEGIN
    RETURN (
           SELECT [name] = [Name],
                [date] = BirthDate
           FROM @children c
           WHERE c.ParentID = @ParentID
           FOR JSON PATH
       )

END
```

Your query can then look like this:

```
SELECT 
    A = [Name]
    ,child =JSON_QUERY(dbo.ChildrenJSON(ParentID))
FROM 
   @parents 
FOR JSON PATH
```

It's clean and easy to read.

This is the output:

```
[
  {
    "A": "Bob",
    "child": [
      {
        "name": "Billy",
        "date": "2000-07-04T00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "name": "Joan",
        "date": "2005-09-19T00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "name": "Sam",
        "date": "2009-01-20T00:00:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "A": "Joe",
    "child": [
      {
        "name": "Billy",
        "date": "2000-07-04T00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "name": "Joan",
        "date": "2005-09-19T00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "name": "Sam",
        "date": "2009-01-20T00:00:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "A": "Sarah",
    "child": [
      {
        "name": "Billy",
        "date": "2000-07-04T00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "name": "Joan",
        "date": "2005-09-19T00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "name": "Sam",
        "date": "2009-01-20T00:00:00"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this schema:

```sql
create table parent(id int primary key, name varchar(100));
create table child(id int primary key, name varchar(100), parent_id int references parent(id));
```

Here is a working solution - abeit more convoluted - that doesn't involve correlated subqueries and only uses `FOR JSON PATH`:

```sql
SELECT
  parent.name AS [name],
  child.json_agg AS [children]
FROM parent
JOIN (
  SELECT
    child.parent_code,
    JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(child.json, ','), ']')) AS json_agg
  FROM (
    SELECT
      child.parent_code,
      (SELECT
        child.name AS [name]
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
      ) AS json
    FROM child
  ) AS child
  GROUP BY child.parent_code
) AS child
ON child.parent_code = parent.code
FOR JSON PATH
```

If you have an index on `child.parent_id`, then using a correlated subquery as suggested, or the equivalent with `CROSS/OUTER APPLY` might be more efficient:

```sql
SELECT
  parent.name AS [name],
  child.json AS [children]
FROM parent
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT
    name AS [name]
  FROM child
  WHERE child.parent_id = parent.id
  FOR JSON PATH
) child(json)
FOR JSON PATH
```

Both queries will return :

```json
[
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "children": [
            { "name": "bar" },
            { "name": "baz" }
        ]
    }
]
```